# regex ":[^]" not working in python re module

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I have a problem in regular expression using re module

pattern = ":[^]", string = ":r", and bool(re.findall(strting, pattern)) should return True However, it returns False like the [pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7nUd.png)

I verified this using https://regexr.com/ and it shows like the [pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hT9rx.png). So I believe the problem is on the re module

How can i show the same result of pic2 in python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the expected behavior cause `re.findall(':r', ':[^]')` means find the strings that match the pattern `:r` in the string `:[^]` i.e. the first argument is the pattern and second argument is the string/text where you need to find a match.

And `[^]` in python regex means none of the characters that's inside the square brackets after caret `^` symbol should match.

If you are looking to find the strings starting with `:` followed by any number of alphabets, following should work:

````py
>>> re.findall(':\w+',':r')
[':r']
```
````